# Remove Javascript generated by Comments

Tags: comments, javascript

In a theme I am working on, the comments form (mostly sure they are both comments form) adds javascript to the header.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://[URL]wp-includes/js/l10n.js?ver=20101110'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://[URL]/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102'></script>
```

When I disable javascript I can still add comments and the comment form still works. So I wish to remove these from my header.

I cannot find any documentation on how to do so, so **How can I remove these?**

Comment: If you remove those, you'll break the comment reply links from moving the comment form around on the page to handle threaded comments properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove scripts in the following manner.

```
function custom_remove_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script('comment-reply');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_remove_scripts' );
```